# How to obtain total children count for all parents in Oracle tree hierarchy?

Tags: sql, tree, oracle11g

I have an Oracle Tree hierarchy structure that is basically similar to the following table called MY_TABLE

```
(LINK_ID,
 PARENT_LINK_ID,
 STEP_ID )
```

with the following sample data within MY_TABLE:

```
LINK_ID     PARENT_LINK_ID      STEP_ID
-----------------------------------------------
A           NULL                0
B           NULL                0
AA          A                   1
AB          A                   1
AAA         AA                  2
BB          B                   1
BBB         BB                  2
BBBA        BBB                 3
BBBB        BBB                 3
```

Based on the above sample data, I need to produce a report that basically returns the total count of rows for all children
of both parent link IDs (top level only required), that is, I need to produce a SQL query that returns the following information, i.e.:

```
PARENT  RESULT COUNT
----------------------------
A       3
B       4
```

So I need to rollup total children that belong to all (parent) link ids, where the LINK_IDs have a PARENT_LINK_ID of NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this:

```
select link, count(*)-1 as "RESULT COUNT"
  from (
    select connect_by_root(link_id) link
    from my_table
    connect by nocycle parent_link_id = prior link_id
    start with parent_link_id is null)
group by link
order by 1 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
WITH parent(LINK_ID1, LINK_ID, asCount) AS
(
  SELECT LINK_ID LINK_ID1, LINK_ID, 1 as asCount  
  from MY_TABLE WHERE PARENT_LINK_ID is null

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT LINK_ID1, t.LINK_ID, asCount+1 as asCount  FROM parent
  INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t ON t.PARENT_LINK_ID =  parent.LINK_ID
    )
select 
  LINK_ID1 "Parent", 
  count(asCount)-1 "Result Count"
From parent 
group by LINK_ID1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0ce2/5)

Comment: Hi techo, tried your solution and modified your SQL Fiddle example by adding another parent "C", i.e. 
insert into MY_TABLE values('C',NULL,0);insert into MY_TABLE values('C1','C',1);insert into MY_TABLE values('C2','C',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C3','C',1);insert into MY_TABLE values('C4','C3',2);insert into MY_TABLE values('C5','C3',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C6','C3',2);insert into MY_TABLE values('C7','C6',3);insert into MY_TABLE values('C8','C6',3); Unfortunately I expected to get a result count of 8 for parent "C", instead I only got 4. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please try `count(asCount)-1` instead of `max(asCount)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same scenario, need to find the below output.

```
PARENT  RESULT COUNT
----------------------------
A       3
B       4   
C       8
```

My table has the below hierarchy.

```
(child,
 parent,
 level)
```

I tried the above code in SQL Fiddle Demo but its not working . Request if anybody can help.

**Table Creation:**

```
create table MY_TABLE (child varchar2(100),
 parent varchar2(100),
 "LEVEL" number);


insert into MY_TABLE values('AA','A',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('AB','A',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('AAA','AA',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('BB','B',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('BBB','BB',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('BBBA','BBB',3);
insert into MY_TABLE values('BBBB','BBB',3);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C1','C',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C2','C',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C3','C',1);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C4','C3',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C5','C3',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C6','C3',2);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C7','C6',3);
insert into MY_TABLE values('C8','C6',3);
```

**Code:**

```
WITH parent(LINK_ID1, LINK_ID, asCount) AS
(
  SELECT child child1, child, 1 as asCount  
  from MY_TABLE WHERE parent is null

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT LINK_ID1, t.child, asCount+1 as asCount  FROM parent
  INNER JOIN MY_TABLE t ON t.parent =  parent.LINK_ID
    )
select 
  LINK_ID1 "Parent", 
  count(asCount)-1 "Result Count"
From parent 
group by LINK_ID1;
```