# PLSQL - implementing function that returns number of children for a node in a tree

Tags: plsql, queue

I want to implement the following function in PLSQL: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-children-given-node-n-ary-tree/.

Is there a way to use queue.push as a function? It seems that it is not possible.

```
// Function to calculate number 
// of children of given node 
int numberOfChildren(Node* root, int x) 
{ 
    // initialize the numChildren as 0 
    int numChildren = 0; 

    if (root == NULL) 
        return 0; 

    // Creating a queue and pushing the root 
    queue<Node*> q; 
    q.push(root); 

    while (!q.empty()) { 
        int n = q.size(); 

        // If this node has children 
        while (n > 0) { 

            // Dequeue an item from queue and 
            // check if it is equal to x 
            // If YES, then return number of children 
            Node* p = q.front(); 
            q.pop(); 
            if (p->key == x) { 
                numChildren = numChildren + p->child.size(); 
                return numChildren; 
            } 

            // Enqueue all children of the dequeued item 
            for (int i = 0; i < p->child.size(); i++) 
                q.push(p->child[i]); 
            n--; 
        } 
    } 
    return numChildren; 
}
```

Comment: I assume then that your tree data is stored in the database as a table? If so, please can you provide sample input data contained in your table? You could then query this table using hierarchical queries, and then manipulate that output to get the count you require

Comment: @Boneist, could you give some reference to hierarchical queries?

Comment: You could search the documentation relevant to your version (which you can select at: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html) or you could google...

Comment: See also similar questions on counting children in oracle hierarchical queries, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900665/how-to-obtain-total-children-count-for-all-parents-in-oracle-tree-hierarchy